# Only root User is able to open LibreOffice

Tags: linux, linux-mint, libreoffice

I am currently using Linux Mint 14 - Nadia as my  Operating System.

The biggest inconvenience right now is not being able to open Libreoffice as a normal user or simply by just double clicking it. Every time I have to run it as root .

```
$sudo libreoffice3.6
```

Even to open a simple document, I have to open do it by the terminal itself

```
$sudo libreoffice3.6 document.doc
```

Here is the error messages I get if I try to open it without being root.

```
$ libreoffice3.6
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed! 
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'
```

Is there anyway to get around this?
-------EDIT--------

Output of ls -l $(which libreoffice3.6)`

```
$ ls -l $(which libreoffice3.6)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Nov 28 15:23 /usr/bin/libreoffice3.6 -> /opt/libreoffice3.6/program/soffice
```

Comment: As root user you run `libreoffice`. Why do you run `libreoffice3.6` with your user instead? Could you add the output of `ls -l $(which libreoffice)` and `ls -l $(which libreoffice3.6)`?

Comment: @jaume , sorry about that , it was a typo it is ibreoffice3.6 with both normal and root user

Comment: @jaume , i have added output of ls -l $(which libreoffice3.6)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps you have the same problem as [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135424/cant-open-any-libre-office-docs-in-12-04/141385#141385) did.

Make sure your user owns `~/.config` and everything in it.

This should do it:

```
sudo chown -R --reference="$HOME" ~/.config
```

It'll change everything in that directory to have the same owner and group as your home directory, which should have the proper values.

Comment: For a more complete fix to remove error "javaldx failed!" and being able to run libroffice (command soffice) from command line with user www-data (inside a web page context), i have to run this > sudo mkdir /var/www/.config; sudo chown www-data  /var/www/.config

Comment: I can confirm @eldy's solution worked

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your username is not identified by linux to have enough privilege to run commands. A few things you should check like:

Make sure you are in `sudo` group with this command.

```
$ getent group sudo
```

It should show output as `sudo:x:27:fayad`

If you are not in it add the username with

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a <user> sudo
```

Crosscheck your `/etc/sudoers` by opening the file and confirming it has the following lines.

`# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command`

`%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: after running `getent group sudo` , i got `sudo:x:27:barath` , which matches , what you posted. and even the /etc/sudoers file is exactly in place , as you have specified...

Comment: Okay, do you get the same results with other applications too? You could also try uninstalling Libreoffice using synaptic and doing a fresh install to see if its the same.

Comment: the other answer fixed it ,thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution has become very easy.

The user in question had not privileges of writing in his own home directory.

There are some files like .config or .java that needs to write in it to run properly.